# Query by existence of a field in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have an index where I need to search whether a field is populated in a class, with what value doesn't matter, just whether it's there or not. Is there any specific way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a value to be indexed for null values via `@Field#indexNullAs()` and then use a NOT query with the null value token you've chosen.